# SudzC shows 'valid' soap response, but null value on iOS's side

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, soap

I'm fairly new to SOAP and iOS, so please bear with me.
I'm attempting to consume a SOAP WS using source SudzC generated.

Looking at the output, things appear to be almost working. I can see the data I need, so data seems to be moving across the wire:

```
2012-03-30 17:26:14.131 EZSystem[892:707] 
Loading: http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/service

2012-03-30 17:26:14.137 EZSystem[892:707]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns="http://database.usah.com/">
<soap:Body>
    <getQB2012CustomerDictionaryXML></getQB2012CustomerDictionaryXML>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

2012-03-30 17:26:14.485 EZSystem[892:707] 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns2:getQB2012CustomerDictionaryXMLResponse
    xmlns:ns2="http://xxxxxx/">
    <return>
        &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?&gt;&lt;!-- 
        &lt;[Quickbooks tag]&gt;Database Column Name&lt;/[Quickbooks tag]&gt;
        --&gt;&lt;CustomerRet database_root_tag="Customers" id="id_customers" 
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </return>
</ns2:getQB2012CustomerDictionaryXMLResponse>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I am sending a string that represents XML, or is XML.

However, the following code returns null:

```
-(void)logIn{
    DictionaryQB2012DatabaseKeyService* service = 
        [DictionaryQB2012DatabaseKeyService service];

    service.logging = YES;

    // Returns NSString*. 
    [service getQB2012CustomerDictionaryXML:self 
        action:@selector(getQB2012CustomerDictionaryXMLHandler:)];
}

// Handle the response from getQB2012CustomerDictionaryXML.
- (void) getQB2012CustomerDictionaryXMLHandler: (id) value {

    // Handle errors
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }


    // Handle faults
    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    // Do something with the NSString* result

    NSString* result = (NSString*)value;
    NSLog(@"getQB2012CustomerDictionaryXML returned the value: %@", result);

}
```

The value is null.

Where in the process is it breaking down? It appears that I am receiving the data I need, but getting it to an OBJ-C string is failing.

Any help would be appreciated,

Dane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SudzC generated SoapRequest.m:

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
    ...
    if(self.logging == YES){
       NSString* response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: self.receivedData 
        encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSLog(@"%@", response);
    }    
    ...
}
```

The response is the raw SOAP response, and it contains the data as expected.

In the same method,

```
CXMLNode* element = [[Soap getNode: [doc rootElement] withName: @"Body"] 
    childAtIndex:0];
```

This line gets the return value from the SOAP response. After some poking around, it turns out "Body" was the problem:

The SOAP response has "S:Body", so changing withName to the proper tag name fixes everything.

This bothers me, as I don't know whether my WS is to fault or what, but I'll take it for now.

Also, the Soap.m may have to be modified, as it uses **"soap"** instead of, say, **"soapenv"**. These values are hard coded, but the change is fairly easy.

Also, the namespace is left empty:

```
[s appendFormat:@"=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" 
xmlns=\"%@\">", ns];
```

This may have to be xmlns:[namespace]=\"%@"...
where namespace is the stripped namespace.

That is:

```
http://namespace/ => namespace
```

Also, you cannot receive a string result and use it as in the examples, at least on my end.
For example:

```
NSString* result = (NSString*) value;
```

should produce null. However this seems to work:

```
NSDictionary* result = (NSDictionary*)value;
NSString* finalResult = [[result allValues] objectAtIndex:0];
```

If anyone is interested, here are the modifications to the Soap.m I made.

```
// Soap.m

NSString* const SOAP_PREFIX = @"soapenv";
NSString* const HTTP_PREFIX = @"http://";
NSUInteger const FORWARD_FLASH_CHARACTER_VALUE = 47;

// Creates the XML request for the SOAP envelope with optional SOAP headers.
+ (NSString*) createEnvelope: (NSString*) method forNamespace: (NSString*) ns         
    forParameters: (NSString*) params withHeaders: (NSDictionary*) headers
    {
        NSMutableString* s = [NSMutableString string];

    [s appendString: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"];
        [s appendString: @"<"];
        [s appendString: SOAP_PREFIX];
        [s appendString:@":Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
            instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\""];
        [s appendString:@" xmlns:"];
        [s appendString: SOAP_PREFIX];

        NSString* rawNamespace = [Soap getRawNamespace:ns];
        [s appendFormat:@"=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" 
            xmlns:%@=\"%@\">", rawNamespace, ns];

        if(headers != nil && headers.count > 0) {
            [s appendString: @"<"];
            [s appendString: SOAP_PREFIX];
            [s appendString:@":Header>"];

            for(id key in [headers allKeys]) {
        if([[headers objectForKey: key] isMemberOfClass: [SoapNil class]])     
                {
                [s appendFormat: @"<%@ xsi:nil=\"true\"/>", key];
        } else {
                [s appendString:[Soap serializeHeader:headers forKey:key]];
        }
        }  
            [s appendString: @"</"];
            [s appendString: SOAP_PREFIX];
            [s appendString:@":Header>"];
    }

    [s appendString: @"<"];
        [s appendString: SOAP_PREFIX];
        [s appendString:@":Body>"];

        NSMutableString* fullMethodName = [NSMutableString string];
        [fullMethodName appendString:rawNamespace];
        [fullMethodName appendString:@":"];
        [fullMethodName appendString:method];

    [s appendFormat: @"<%@>%@</%@>", fullMethodName,[params 
            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"], 
            fullMethodName];


        [s appendString: @"</"];
        [s appendString: SOAP_PREFIX];
        [s appendString:@":Body>"];
        [s appendString: @"</"];
        [s appendString: SOAP_PREFIX];
        [s appendString:@":Envelope>"];
    return s;
}


+(NSString*)getRawNamespace:(NSString *)value{
    if([value hasPrefix:HTTP_PREFIX]){
        NSString* rawNamespace = [value substringFromIndex:([HTTP_PREFIX length])];

        if([rawNamespace length] == 0){
            return @"";
        }
        // strip out a trailing slash
        if([rawNamespace characterAtIndex:([rawNamespace length]- 1)] ==             
            FORWARD_FLASH_CHARACTER_VALUE){
            NSRange range = NSMakeRange (0, [rawNamespace length] - 1);
            rawNamespace = [rawNamespace substringWithRange:(range)];
        }
        return rawNamespace;           
    }
    else{
        return value;
    }
}
```